# Can't find mule-ee.xsd for mule 3.4

Tags: java, xml, xsd, mule, mule-studio

I can't seem to manage finding the proper url for mule-ee.xsd schema for version 3.4, browsing http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/ I see no entry pointing to this version.

```
---------------------------------------------
[DIR]   Parent Directory        -
[DIR]   2.2/    31-Jul-2009 16:52   -
[DIR]   3.0/    13-Oct-2009 08:19   -
[DIR]   3.1/    06-Dec-2010 18:50   -
[DIR]   3.2/    10-Sep-2011 18:10   -
[DIR]   3.3/    25-Jun-2012 09:41   - 
---------------------------------------------
```

Was wondering if anyone else ran into this issue and what was the way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This schema is part of the EE distribution. You can find it embedded in `mule-module-spring-config-ee-3.4.0.jar`.